# Python: Printing vertically

Tags: for-loop

The final code will print the distance between states. I'm trying to print the menu with the names of the states numbered and vertically. I really struggle to find my mistakes.

This code doesn't raise any error, it just prints nothing, empty.

```
state_data = """
LA  34.0522°N 118.2437°W
Florida 27.6648°N 81.5158°W
NY 40.7128°N 74.0060°W"""

states = []

import re
state_data1 = re.sub("[°N@°E]", "", state_data)

def process_states(string):
    states_temp = string.split()
    states = [(states_temp[x], float(states_temp[x + 1]), float(states_temp[x + 2])) for x in
                range(0, len(states_temp), 3)]
    return states

def menu():
    for state_data in range(state_data1):
        print(f'{state_data + 1} {name[number]}')
```

Comment: Does this code raise an error or does it just print something wrongly? Please edit your post and add the error message or program output. It's easier for us to help when we can just look at the post instead of running your code and guessing what's wrong

Comment: You can split `airport_data` on newline then again on space, but it might be better to change the `airport_data` to a list of tuples or maybe a dictionary of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is, your code does not print anything without errors because you never actually execute `process_airports()` nor `menu()`.

You have to call them like this at the end of your script:

```
something = process_airports(airport_data1)
menu()
```

This will now raise some errors though. So let's address them.
The `menu()` function will raise an error because neither `name` nor `number` are defined and because you are trying to apply the `range` function over a string (`airport_data1`) instead of an integer.

First fixing the range error: you mixed two ideas in your for-loop: iterating over the elements in your list `airport_data1` and iterating over the **indexes** of the elements in the list.

You have to choose one (we'll see later that you can do both at once), in this example, I choose to iterate over the indexes of the list.

Then, since neither `name` nor `number` exists anywhere they will raise an error. You always need to declare variables somewhere, however, in this case they are not needed at all so let's just remove them:

```
def menu(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print(f'{i + 1} {data[i]}')

processed_airports = process_airports(airport_data1)
menu(processed_airports)
```

Considering `data` is the output of `process_airports()`

---

Now for some general advices and improvements.

First, global variables.
Notice how you can access `airport_data1` within the `menu()` function just fine, while it works this is not something recommended, it's usually better to explicitly pass variables as arguments.

Notice how in the function I proposed above, every single variable is declared in the function itself, there is no information coming from a higher scope. Again, this is not mandatory but makes the code way easier to work with and understand.

```
airport_data = """
Alexandroupoli  40.855869°N 25.956264°E
Athens 37.936389°N 23.947222°E
Chania  35.531667°N 24.149722°E
Chios   38.343056°N 26.140556°E
Corfu 39.601944°N 19.911667°E"""

airports = []

import re
airport_data1 = re.sub("[°N@°E]", "", airport_data)

def process_airports(string):
    airports_temp = string.split()
    airports = [(airports_temp[x], float(airports_temp[x + 1]), float(airports_temp[x + 2])) for x in
                range(0, len(airports_temp), 3)]
    return airports

def menu(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print(f'{i + 1} {data[i]}')

# I'm adding the call to the functions for clarity
data = process_airports(airport_data1)
menu(data)
```

The printed menu now looks like that:

```
1 ('Alexandroupoli', 40.855869, 25.956264)
2 ('Athens', 37.936389, 23.947222)
3 ('Chania', 35.531667, 24.149722)
4 ('Chios', 38.343056, 26.140556)
5 ('Corfu', 39.601944, 19.911667)
```

Second and this is mostly fyi, but you can access both the index of a iterable and the element itself by looping over `enumerate()` meaning, the following function will print the exact same thing as the one with `range(len(data))`. This is handy if you need to work with both the element itself and it's index.

```
def menu(data):
    for the_index, the_element in enumerate(data):
        print(f'{the_index + 1} {the_element}')
```

Comment: Of course it is, what you have as `('Alexandroupoli', 40.855869, 25.956264)` is a structure called a "tuple". It behaves more or less the same as a list so you can just select any element you want by using square brackets just like you would for a list. In your case that would mean replace the print by this `print(f'{i + 1} {data[i][0]}')` where `data[i]` allow you to select the element at index `i` in `data` and `[0]` accessing the first element inside that tuple.